# Why is the type expression valid with lesser number of arguments?

Tags: typescript, function, parameters, arguments

I'm learning Typescript and am currently on the chapter dealing with functions.
Take a look at this code:

```js
type ArrMapCallbackFunctionTypeExpression = (value: number, index: number, arr: number[]) => number

function map (arr: number[], cb: ArrMapCallbackFunctionTypeExpression): number[] {
    return arr.map(cb);
}

function callback0 () { return 1; }

function callback1 (value: number) {
    return value;
}

function callback2 (value: number, index: number) {
    return value;
}

function callback3 (value: number, index: number, arr: number[]) {
    return value;
}

map([1, 2, 3], callback1)
map([1, 2, 3], callback2)
map([1, 2, 3], callback3)
```

Can someone tell me why `callback0`, `callback1` and `callback2` in the above code match the type `ArrMapCallbackFunctionTypeExpression`?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are free to ignore any arguments that are passed to them or not declare them at all. The argument types are evaluated left to right and if they match then it's good to go.